# How to use SHGetFolderPathA to specify location for saving video?

Tags: c++, api, genicam

I am trying to save an avi video to a file. For that I am using a special API from the company that produces these cameras, which already has all the functions that allow me to set up the avi file and do every other pertinent action. However, I am not able to get to the file where the video has been saved once I run the code.

My program compiles perfectly fine. However, I cannot find the location of the file where the .avi video was saved. I have tried changing the CSIDL_ to different locations, but I cannot access any of the locations.

```
`// Configure the video file settings.
        pIStVideoFiler->SetMaximumFrameCountPerFile(iMaximumCountOfImagesPerFile);
        pIStVideoFiler->SetVideoFileFormat(StVideoFileFormat_AVI2);
        pIStVideoFiler->SetVideoFileCompression(StVideoFileCompression_MotionJPEG);
        pIStVideoFiler->SetFPS(fps);

// Get the path of the video files.
    char szPath[MAX_PATH];
    SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_MYVIDEO, NULL, 0, szPath);

// Register the file name of the video files
for (size_t i = 0; i < nCountOfVideoFiles; i++)
    {
    GenICam::gcstring strFileName(szPath);
    strFileName.append("\\SaveVideo");
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    strFileName.append(ss.str().c_str());
    strFileName.append(".avi");
    pIStVideoFiler->RegisterFileName(strFileName);
    }`
```

My expectations are to be able to tell the function to save the video files to a location I can access. Please, keep in mind that I am a relatively new to programming in C++.